# Elasticsearch: Could not parse date from the value

Tags: python, elasticsearch, python-dateutil, elasticsearch-dsl

I am getting this error, some times, while I scan documents for an export:

```
elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions:ValidationException: 
Could not parse date from the value (u'2016-11-03T21:46:09.278914+00:00')
```

Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/search.py", line 666, in scan
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py", line 216, in from_es
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/document.py", line 108, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/utils.py", line 339, in __init__
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/field.py", line 76, in deserialize
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/elasticsearch_dsl/field.py", line 224, in _deserialize
```

Using:

- Elasticsearch 2.4.0
- elasticsearch==2.4.0
- elasticsearch-dsl==2.1.0

Any ideas why and how to fix it?

**Edit:** Parsing the date works, as can be seen in the example below taken from official elasticsearch_dls repo https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/blob/master/elasticsearch_dsl/field.py#L222:

```
from dateutil import parser

x = '2016-11-03T21:46:09.278914+00:00'
print parser.parse(x) # will output 2016-11-03 21:46:09.278914+00:00
```

Comment: Does it work if there are 5 or 7 digits after the decimal point, not 6?

Comment: if I run the example above, it works and it does the same thing as it does elastic dsl

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an actual MVE here, so I'm not sure how to replicate this. My only suspicion was that sometimes with format-independent parsers like that 6-digit numbers cause problems because they are mistaken for either MMDDYY or HHMMSS.

Comment: I'm using datetime objects from python, so I can't control the serialization